# How do I apply a border to a <a> link?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a red 2px border when a customer hovers over one of my three 'service widgets' on my website https://tomnicholls.co on the homepage. I can't figure out where to apply the code as I can't find a container? I can't even seem to add a regular border never mind a border on :hover.

I have tried applying code to .col-link & .col-link .custom-link and have also tried giving the column a class and applying code to that as well as giving the actual content block a class (btn-widget) and applying css to that but nothing seems to be working.

```css
.btn-widget {
    width: 328px !important;
    margin-left: 72px !important;
    border-left: 2px !important;
    border-right: 2px !important;
    border-top: 2px !important;
    border-bottom: 2px !important;
    border-color: #c92228 !important;
    z-index: 1000;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

I would like to solve the problem and have a border on hover

Comment: The way to add a 2px black border to an element that has CSS class `widget` would be `.widget  {border-bottom: 2px solid black;}`, the way to add a 2px red border to hovered element with class `widget` would be `.widget:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid red;}`. However, you are talking about an entire webpage, and there could be other things that mess your CSS. Please, provide a minimal example, and also fix you formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with this :

```
a.col-link.custom-link:hover {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I am getting a slight flash of purple on hover, before the red. Can you see that?

Comment: Hope to read that, do not forget to mark this answer as accepted in order to close it.
If you have a second question, please open a new ticket.